# Existence of constant $c$ such that polynomial $P(x_1,\ldots,x_d)+c$ factors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algorithms

While trying to simplify multivariate polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$,

I was wondering,

1. if it is possible to decide, if there is a constant $c$, such that
   for a given polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ the expression 
   $p(x_1,\ldots,x_d) + c$ factors into linear factors
2. if it is possible to find such constants $c$
3. if one can parametrize the constants $c$ as function of the coefficients of the given polynomial
4. if constants do not work, perhaps a linear term might do the job

My smallest test polynomial starting with dimension 4, is the following

$p_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) =\\
+750x_2x_3x_4-750x_1x_3x_4\\
+375x_2x_4^2-375x_1x_4^2+375x_2^2x_4-375x_1^2x_4\\
+375x_2x_3^2-375x_1x_3^2+375x_2^2x_3-375x_1^2x_3\\
+125x_2^3-125x_1^3\\
+150x_2x_4-150x_1x_4+150x_2x_3-150x_1x_3\\
+75x_2^2-75x_1^2
+10x_2-10x_1$

which is essentially an alternating sum of binomial coefficients.

**Edit 2019-07-29**
The polynomial from Hagen's answer divided by 5

$p_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) =\\
+75x_4^2+75x_3x_4+75x_2x_4+75x_1x_4\\
+75x_3^2+75x_3x_4+75x_2x_3+75x_1x_3\\
+25x_2^2+25x_1x_2+25x_1^2\\
+15x_1+15x_2+30x_3+30x_4+2$.

So essentially, what I'm looking for is an algorithm,
which adds constants and splits off linear factors repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be the total degree of $p$ and assume $p(x_1,\ldots, x_r)-c$ splits  into (apparently $D$) linear factors.
Fix $q\in \Bbb Q$. In general, $f(t):=p(t,\ldots,t,qt)\in\Bbb Q[t]$ will have degree $D$. There are two exceptions:
If $p-c$ has a linear factor $a_1x_1+\cdots +a_dx_d-b$ 
with $a_1+\cdots +a_{d-1}+qa_d=0$, then $f$ is either constant (if $b=0$) and that constant is $c$; or it is of degree $D$ minus the number of such linear factors with $b\ne 0$.If we find $q$ with either of these properties, we have found some condition on the possible form of the linear factors.

In your example, we note that *any* choice of $q$ makes $f(t)=0$, i.e., if there is such $c$ as desired, then it must be $$\fbox{$c=0$}$$ and one of the factors (depending on $q$) is of the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4$ with $a_1+a_2+a_3+qa_4=0$. As there are infinitely many $q$ and inly finitely many factors, we infer that for one factor $a_1+a_2+a_3=0=a_4$.

We find the same result when placing the $q$ to $x_3$ instead of $x_4$. So either there is a second linear factor with $a_1+a_2+a_4=a_3=0$, or it is the same factor as above and $a_1+a_2=a_3=a_4=0$. Indeed one verifies that $$\fbox{$x_2-x_1$}$$ is a factor, and after getting rid of it we are left with 
$$ 750 x_3x_4+375x_4^2+375 x_2x_4+375x_1x_4+375x_3^2+375x_2x_3+375x_1x_3
+125x_2^2+125x_2x_1+125x_1^2+150x_4+150x_3+75x_2+75x_1+10.$$
Let's plug in $q_1=x_2=x_3=t$ and $x_4=qt$ again:
$$750t^2q+375t^2q^2+375t^2q+375t^2q+375t^2+375t^2+375t^2+125t^2+125t^2+125t^2+150tq+150t+75t+75t+10\\
=(375q^2+1500q    +1500)t^2 +(\ldots)t+10\\
=375(q+2)^2t^2+(\ldots)t+10$$
is of lower degree only for $q=-2$. Therefore all remaining linear factors must be of the form $ a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+a_4x_4-b$ with $a_1+a_2+a_3=2a_4$. It is hardly surprising that we find by the same method that $a_1+a_2+a_4=2a_3$ for both factors, hence $a_1+a_2=a_3=a_4$ for both.

With $x_2=qt$ instead, we arrive at
$$ (2375+875q+125q^2)t^2+\ldots = 125(q^2+7q+19)t^2+\ldots$$
and that quadratic on $q$ has no rational solution. We conclude that the linear factors cannot exist after all (at least not with integer or rational coefficients) or that I made a mistake in the substitution :)

Comment: You have written "If we find q with either of these properties, we have found some condition on the possible form of the linear factors". What can be said for the other cases. Can this heuristic made be more explicit?